# Error linking against boost python

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

Here's my simple HelloWorld program

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

void greet() {
    // do nothing
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(HelloWorld)
{
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

and here's my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(HW)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC
HelloWorld.cpp
)

add_library(HelloWorld SHARED ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

However, I have been unable to build this simple program, with this build error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
      boost::python::detail::none() in HelloWorld.cpp.o
      boost::python::api::object::object() in HelloWorld.cpp.o
  "boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())", referenced from:
      _PyInit_HelloWorld in HelloWorld.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

What am I missing? Sorry if this looks like a newbie question but I'm actually stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the a link to the Python library (as opposed to the Boost Python library)

Try something like `find_package(Python)` then `target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${Python_LIBRARY})`

Additionally (based on this post https://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/107) the name of the library you're building doesn't match the name given in `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`. Change it to `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libHelloWorld)` because cmake implicitly adds a `lib` to the module name.

Comment: I changed to what you suggested and it still cannot link; and why did you suggest removing linking to `boost_python`?

The link in your post also has example linking against `boost_python` (`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(yay ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`)

Comment: I didn't suggest removing the link to boost python (sorry if that was unclear! I just wanted to emphasise that the python and boost python libraries are different). I meant adding a target_link_libraries for python too. Keep linking to boost...

Comment: Still same error even after adding `find_package(Python)` and `target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${Python_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: If I change `find_package(Python)` to `find_package(PythonLibs)` and `Python_LIBRARY` to `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` then it works.

However, I still don't understand
    (i) Why in many tutorials, linking against PYTHON_LIBRARIES seems not needed
    (ii) What's the difference between Python (your suggestion) and PythonLibs

Comment: I don't know why many tutorials don't seem to link against Python directly. `find_package(Python)` vs `find_package(PythonLibs)` is just a mistake on my part!

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this issue. I just asked a sub-sequent question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245558/how-to-link-with-python3-libs-with-cmake). If you know how to troubleshoot that, that would be great :D.