# How to link with Python3 Libs with cmake?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, boost-python

I have Python3 installed via `brew install python3`. However, `cmake` cannot find PythonLibs 3. Here's the header of my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
```

When I ran cmake, I got this error message

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", but required is at least "3" (found /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib)
```

Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694772/does-cmake-support-python3 - it's a very similar problem. The simplest thing suggestion would be to manually set the paths to the Python headers and libraries, but it isn't a great solution. I know nothing about `brew` and how it affects things...

Comment: Thanks, the solution in that link works, although it no longer makes my code cross platform :(.

And I asked another question on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267718/cannot-import-boost-python-module, if you don't mind answering.

Thanks a lot @DavidW.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are using CMake >= 3.0, you can you `find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)` see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython.html

That would for instance give you for:

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

message("Python_FOUND:${Python_FOUND}")
message("Python_VERSION:${Python_VERSION}")
message("Python_Development_FOUND:${Python_Development_FOUND}")
message("Python_LIBRARIES:${Python_LIBRARIES}")
```

Results:

```
Python_FOUND:TRUE
Python_VERSION:3.8.0
Python_Development_FOUND:TRUE
Python_LIBRARIES:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so
```

Comment: me/qgb/github/binapi/examples/websockets/main.cpp
/home/qgb/github/binapi/examples/websockets/main.cpp:20:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   20 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[2/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cashflow.dir/main.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: sub

Comment: @CSQGB Installing the package `libpython3-dev` should solve your issue.

Comment: I am using vcpkg and executed vcpkg install boost python3:x64-linux

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, this happened because I was using an older version of cmake (2.8 instead of 3+) that didn't know about Python 3.4 (it gave up after 3.3.)

The solution was to go into the CMakeLists.txt file and add an "additional versions" directive ABOVE the find_package:

`set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)`

You could probably also fix it by upgrading your version of cmake. But the above worked for me with cmake 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this is that CMake can't ever find Python 3 when it is installed from brew on OSX. It looks like the CMake devs know that `FindPythonLibs` sucks and have [a ticket to revamp it](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16142) but it doesn't look like it will happen any time soon.

I believe the Python interpreter itself knows where its libraries and headers are so I think the best thing to do would be to run it to find out. To get the path to the Python interpreter I would force the user to specify it manually. One of the big issues with Python is that lots of software includes its own copy so you'll end up with 5 copies of it on your system. The chance of picking up the wrong one is just too high. Get the user to specify the correct one.